# Pass newly created object to after_create callback in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, redis, callback

Everytime an object has been created i want to enqueue it in a Redis queue to check for certain properties. How can i add the created object directly as a parameter to the callback? So my redis job would do something like this:

```
class FurtherProcessCarJob
 #....

 def self.perform(order)
   puts order.id
 end 
end
```

whereas in the model

```
after_create Resque.enqueue FurtherProcessCar, #self
```

It is possible to hook a method to the callback and there look for the car again and the enqueue the object, but is it possible to do it directly?

Comment: `after_create { | record |  Resque.enqueue record }` should be working as well? see https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html first example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I understand your question, something like this should work

```
class YourModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  #....
  after_create :enqueue_to_redis

  private 

  def enque_to_redis
     Resque.enqueue self, other_args
  end 
end
```

Comment: Excellent! I tried smth similar, or maybe even that, but it was not working ;)

Answer (score 0):

Add in your model

```
class YourModel < ApplicationRecord

 after_commit do 
    YourModelJob.perform_later(self.id)
  end

end
```